# How do you use sp_getProcedureColumns()?

Tags: advantage-database-server

How do you use sp_getProcedureColumns()?

I cannot find any documentation for it.

Thanks,

Howard

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why that system procedure is not documented.  However, I believe it uses the same syntax as [sp_GetColumns](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/master_sp_getcolumns.htm?zoom_highlightsub=sp_getcolumns).  For example,

```
execute procedure sp_getProcedureColumns(null, null, 'myAEP', null );
```

And based on a comment in another question, you might also be interested in `AdsCommand.DeriveParameters`.  Here is an example:

```
AdsCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SomeProcedure";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.DeriveParameters();
foreach ( AdsParameter p in cmd.Parameters )
   Console.WriteLine( "{0}, {1}, {2}", p.ParameterName, p.DbType.ToString(), 
                        p.Direction.ToString() );
```